# How to remove foot stink?

Tags: cleaning, smell

Every morning I have a bath and leave for work. Recently during rainy season my feet start to stink once I reach my work. As its an AC environment, the smell is prominent, which is kind of embarrassing.
These points might help you deduce the problem.

- I live in a place where there are lot of potholes and water fills in soon
- The roads are dirty, and I wear sandals.
- I am pretty sure that the dirty water sticks to the sandals and my feet and dries up to stink

The problem is that I cannot wash my feet and sandals in the restroom of my office. So is there any convenient and easy solution?
PS:I have read [this link](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/14113/how-to-deodorize-the-bad-odour-in-footwear-due-to-wetness), but it doesn't answer my problem.

Comment: [Does not need a life hack.](https://www.google.com/search?q=foot%20powder)

Answer (score 4):

A little late, but try to sprinkle a little **Sodium Bicarbonate** (i.e. baking soda) on your sandals/slippers/inside your shoes.

Its proven that it prevents / lessens a lot of bad smells, including foot odor. Just sprinkle a pinch inside your shoe, and wear it normally.

You can get it at any local pharmacy, or convenience store.

For reference, and some of its other uses:

[10 Really Bad Smells Erased With Baking Soda](http://www.top10homeremedies.com/kitchen-ingredients/10-bad-smells-erased-baking-soda.html)

[Baking Soda Uses: To Remove Splinters -- and to Address Many Other Health Needs](http://articles.mercola.com/sites/articles/archive/2012/08/27/baking-soda-natural-remedy.aspx)

P.S. It also works wonderfully for preventing one's **sweat** from smelling, I frequently play Basketball, so I can safely say, **it works**.

Answer (score 3):

As you clean your feet during each bath, I suspect **footwear** to be initial culprit of stink or bad smell as we say.

There are bacteria residing on our footwear which contributes to bad smell unless some bad smelling substance is lying on your footwear

This [post](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/14113/11420) have answers to better ways of cleaning foot wear.

**Next culprit is feet**

Keep cleaning feet by soap wash as and when possible

> A best way to keep feet off bacteria is applying turmeric paste over
>   it.

Stay clean, stay healthy !

Answer (score 2):

Keep a clean pair of enclosed shoes, rather than open sandals, at work.

Carry a spare fresh pair of socks with you to work every day, in a sealed bag to take them home again at the end of the day.

Comment: And where do i keep the sandal or whatever i use to get to the office?

Comment: @BhagyeshChaudhari in a sealed plastic bag, preferably.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can't wash your sandals and feet in the restroom at work, you could bring a container of pre-moistened towelettes into a bathroom stall with you and wipe your feet & sandals clean there.  Then you could either flush the towelettes (if the package says they're safe to flush), or bring them out discretely and throw them away.

Answer (score 1):

Something I do when normal stink removal methods aren't working for me, such as spending extra time cleaning my feet and using foot powder in my shoes to dry them and absorb odors, is to clean my feet after my shower with rubbing alcohol. After you dry your feet, just get a corner of a rag wet with the isopropyl alcohol and scrub your feet, Especially between the toes, and let them air dry.

If that method doesn't work when done at home, you could bring the alcohol and rag to work with you, or even just keep them there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: foot powder seems like a nice idea.

Comment: Some foot powders have soothing agents in them, which can feel really good too.